# Server cannot receive the clients message in c winsock programming

Tags: c, sockets, winsock, winsock2

Hello Friends I am a newbie to socket programming in c.I read a few tutorials in the net and started working.The programs below are my socket client and server programs using winsock2 library in WINDOWS.

Whenever i run the program, there is no error until the server accepts the clients connection.But after the client sends the message the server cannot receive the message. The WSAGetLastError() function returns the error code as 10038.I tried changing the port, increasing and decreasing the message size.
help me friends.

Server code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<WinSock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
WSADATA wsa;
int r;
char buf[4];
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa);

SOCKET s= socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

if ( s==INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("\n failed to create socket error code : %d ",WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

sockaddr_in sin,cl;
sin.sin_family=AF_INET;
sin.sin_port=htons(80);
sin.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;

if(bind (s,(sockaddr *)&sin,sizeof(sin))==SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("\nSocket not Bound\n");
    WSACleanup(); 
    return 1;
}

r=listen(s,2);
if(r==SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("\nListening Failed\n");
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
printf("\n Listening\n");

SOCKET client;
r= sizeof(sockaddr_in);
printf("\n Ready to accept");
while (client=accept(s,(sockaddr *)&cl,&r)!= INVALID_SOCKET)
{
printf("\nNew client found\n\n");
if(client == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("\nError connecting client error code : %d ",WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

r=recv(client,buf,4,0);
if(r==SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("\nSocket not connected error code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

printf("%s\n",buf);
}
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Client code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

WSADATA wsa;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa);
int r;
char *buf="data";

SOCKET t=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if(t==SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("\nFailed socket error code : %d ",WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

sockaddr_in server;
server.sin_family=AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.142");
server.sin_port=htons(80);

printf("\nConnecting\n");
r=connect(t,(sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server));
if(r==SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("\nFailed to connect error code : %d ",WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
printf("\n connected\n");
 
 printf("\nSending data\n");
 r=send(t,buf,strlen(buf),0);
 if (r==SOCKET_ERROR)
 {
     printf("\nFailed to connect error code : %d ",WSAGetLastError());
     WSACleanup();
     return 1;
 }
 printf("\n Data sent\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: One thing you have to observe, is that strings in C are null-terminated, which means theres a symbol `\0` *after* the string that marks where it ends. So `strlen()` of `"data"` is 4 because it has 4 characters, but its total size is actually 5 bytes. You have to send the `\0` too, otherwise the `buf` in server-side won't be a valid C string and may cause undefined behaviour when you try to `printf()` it.

Comment: Also, I don't know what kind of behaviour you will get without specifying the protocol. In this case it seems `socket()` should receive `IPPROTO_TCP` as third parameter, not `0`.

Comment: It's well worth taking a look at ZeroMQ. It's a far, far easier way of using network connections than dealing with raw sockets. Take a look at http://zeromq.org/distro:microsoft-windows for downloads, and search for "ZeroMQ Guide".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we look up what 10038 means.

```
SAENOTSOCK
10038 (0x2736)
An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.
```

OK, so you think you have a socket, but you really don't in one of your calls.  You weren't very specific on which `WSAGetLastError()` function was returning 10038, but I'm going to guess the call after this one:

```
while (client=accept(s,(sockaddr *)&cl,&r)!= INVALID_SOCKET)
```

In C, the `!=` is handled first, and then the assignment.  So you end up with the socket returned by `accept` being compared to `INVALID_SOCKET`, and then that boolean value being assigned to `client`.  You want the socket to be assigned and then compared, so you should use parentheses around the assignment:

```
while ((client = accept(s,(sockaddr *)&cl,&r)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
```

Also, `socket()` returns `INVALID_SOCKET` and not `SOCKET_ERROR`, although confusing the two won't cause a problem by coincidence.

Further, you need to null-terminate the string on the receiver side if you are going to print it.

```
char buf[5];  /* 4 characters + 1 null-terminator */
...
buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = '\0';    /* enforce that the buffer is always null terminated regardless of what the sender sends. */
```

Comment: thanks for the help indiv. Now the code works just fine. But still the while loop which i added to keep the connection live is executing only once. could you help me with that too

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific.  It looks to me like you don't have a while loop to keep the connection live in the code you posted.  If you'd like help with some new code, you should post a new question.